# BigInteger, Integer too large

Tags: java

Trying to use `BigInteger` first time, and this is my code:

```
    public class Factx
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger[] asd = new BigInteger[10];
        asd[0] = 123456458979851322316546445665;
        System.out.println(asd[0]);
    }
}
```

Compiling this, gives an error `Integer number too large`

I also tried changing,

```
        asd[0] = new BigInteger(123456458979851322316546445665);
```

referred some other questions as well, didn't do much help, am I missing something? Whats the best fix? Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

`asd[0] = 123456458979851322316546445665;` doesn't work for two reasons :

1. You can't assign a primitive value to a variable whose type is a reference type (unless that reference type is the wrapper class of that primitive type, like `Integer` is the wrapper of `int`).
2. `123456458979851322316546445665` is too large for an `int` literal (and even if you add `L` suffix, it will still be too large for a `long` literal). This also explains why `asd[0] = new BigInteger(123456458979851322316546445665);` doesn't work.

Instead, use the `BigInteger` constructor that takes a `String` :

```
    BigInteger[] asd = new BigInteger[10];
    asd[0] = new BigInteger("123456458979851322316546445665");
    System.out.println(asd[0]);
```

Output:

```
123456458979851322316546445665
```

Comment: Thanks, And as I read these are Immutable like String, Can I perform the add() method on the saved value?

Comment: @oblivion You can perform `add()`. It will return a new `BigInteger` instance.

Comment: Thanks Eran :) , and is there a limit to BigInts value?

Comment: @oblivion I don't believe there is a limit (at least I couldn't find one mentioned in the Javadoc), beside the obvious memory limit (which you are probably not going to reach, unless you generate a large number of very large `BigInteger` instances).

Comment: Thanks for helping ! :)

Comment: @oblivion the limit is around 10^20,686,623,774
 i.e. the maximum number of bits you can store in an `int[]` Note: some operations like toString() will fail if you have more than Integer.MAX_VALUE digits.

Answer (score 0):

Create BigInteger via

```
asd[0] =  new BigInteger("123456458979851322316546445665");
```

BigInteger doesn't accept explicit cast from integer to BigInteger, only via constructors.